# índice tem que se referir a uma coordenada de uma cadeia de caracteres

Tags: substring

O meu código dá erro nesta EXATA linha, eu já refiz inteiro e mesmo assim dá o mesmo erro. trata-se de um jogo da forca:

> vLetraA = vLetraA.Substring(x, 1);

código completo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int vAcertos = 0, vErros = 0, x, vTam, i;
            string vPalavra = "", vLetraD, vLetra, vAtual, vAnterior, vLetraA;
            bool vAcertou;
            string[] Palavra = new string[8];
            Random aleatory = new Random();
            Palavra[0] = "Batman";
            Palavra[1] = "Coringa";
            Palavra[2] = "Penguim";
            Palavra[3] = "Duas Caras";
            Palavra[4] = "Harleyquinn";
            Palavra[5] = "Morcego Humano";
            Palavra[6] = "Drax";
            Palavra[7] = "Robin";

            i = aleatory.Next(0, 8);
            vPalavra = Palavra[i];
            vAnterior = ""; vAtual = ""; //declaração Primária;
            vTam = vPalavra.Length; //vTam é o tamanho do vPalavra
            for (x = 0; x < vTam; x++)
            {
                vAtual = vAtual + "-";
            }
            Console.SetCursorPosition(25, 12);
            Console.Write(vAtual);
            do
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 9);
                Console.Write("escreva uma letra: ");
                vLetraD = Console.ReadLine();
                vLetraA = vAtual; vAcertou = false;
                vAtual = "";
                for (x = 0; x < vTam; x++)
                {
                    vLetra = vPalavra.Substring(x, 1);
                    vLetraA = vLetraA.Substring(x, 1);
                    if (vLetraD == vLetra && vLetraA == "-")
                    {
                        vAtual = vAtual + vLetra;
                        vAcertos++;
                        vAcertou = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (vLetraA == "-")
                        {
                            vAtual = vAtual + "-";
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.SetCursorPosition(25, 12);
                Console.Write(vAtual);
                if (vAcertou == false)
                {
                    vErros++;
                    MostraCorpo(vErros);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
                Console.ReadKey();
            } while (vErros != 6 && vAcertos != vTam);


        }
        static void janela(int L1, int C1, int L2, int C2)
        {
            int x;
            for (x = L1; x <= L2; x++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(C1, x); Console.Write("║");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(C2, x); Console.Write("║");
            }
            for (x = C1; x <= C2; x++)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, L1); Console.Write("═");
                Console.SetCursorPosition(x, L2); Console.Write("═");
            }
            Console.SetCursorPosition(C1, L1); Console.Write("╔");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(C2, L1); Console.Write("╗");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(C1, L2); Console.Write("╚");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(C2, L2); Console.Write("╝");
        }
        static void MostraCorpo(int p)
        {
            switch (p)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(13, 7);
                    Console.Write("O");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(13, 8);
                    Console.Write(" /|\\ ");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(13, 7);
                    Console.Write(" /\\");
                    break;
            }
        }
        static void MostraForca()
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 5);
            Console.Write("____");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 6);
            Console.WriteLine("|  |");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 7);
            Console.WriteLine("|");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 8);
            Console.WriteLine("|");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, Amigo!
Acredito que você esteja precisando utilizar o [StringBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder). Segue abaixo o código com o ajuste:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
  class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int vAcertos = 0, vErros = 0, x, vTam, i;
        string vPalavra = "", vLetra, vAtual, vAnterior, vLetraA;
        char vLetraD;
        bool vAcertou;
        string[] Palavra = new string[8];
        Random aleatory = new Random();
        Palavra[0] = "Batman";
        Palavra[1] = "Coringa";
        Palavra[2] = "Penguim";
        Palavra[3] = "Duas Caras";
        Palavra[4] = "Harleyquinn";
        Palavra[5] = "Morcego Humano";
        Palavra[6] = "Drax";
        Palavra[7] = "Robin";

        i = aleatory.Next(0, 8);
        vPalavra = Palavra[i];
        var PalavraAuxiliar = new StringBuilder(vPalavra);
        vAnterior = ""; vAtual = ""; //declaração Primária;
        vTam = vPalavra.Length; //vTam é o tamanho do vPalavra
        for (x = 0; x < vTam; x++)
        {
            PalavraAuxiliar.Replace(PalavraAuxiliar[x], '-');
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(25, 12);
        Console.Write(PalavraAuxiliar);
        do
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 9);
            Console.Write("escreva uma letra: ");
            vLetraD =char.Parse( Console.ReadLine());
            vAcertou = false;
            for (int posicao = 0; posicao < vTam; posicao++)
            {

                /*Principal Alteração*/
                if(vLetraD == vPalavra[posicao]){
                    PalavraAuxiliar[posicao] = vLetraD;
                    vAcertou = true;
                }
            }

            Console.SetCursorPosition(25, 12);
            Console.Write(PalavraAuxiliar);
            if (!vAcertou)
            {
                vErros++;
                MostraCorpo(vErros);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        } while (vErros != 6 && vAcertos != vTam);


    }
    static void janela(int L1, int C1, int L2, int C2)
    {
        int x;
        for (x = L1; x <= L2; x++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(C1, x); Console.Write("║");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(C2, x); Console.Write("║");
        }
        for (x = C1; x <= C2; x++)
        {
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, L1); Console.Write("═");
            Console.SetCursorPosition(x, L2); Console.Write("═");
        }
        Console.SetCursorPosition(C1, L1); Console.Write("╔");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(C2, L1); Console.Write("╗");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(C1, L2); Console.Write("╚");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(C2, L2); Console.Write("╝");
    }
    static void MostraCorpo(int p)
    {
        switch (p)
        {
            case 1:
                Console.SetCursorPosition(13, 7);
                Console.Write("O");
                break;
            case 2:
                Console.SetCursorPosition(13, 8);
                Console.Write(" /|\\ ");
                break;
            case 3:
                Console.SetCursorPosition(13, 7);
                Console.Write(" /\\");
                break;
        }
    }
    static void MostraForca()
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 5);
        Console.Write("____");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 6);
        Console.WriteLine("|  |");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 7);
        Console.WriteLine("|");
        Console.SetCursorPosition(10, 8);
        Console.WriteLine("|");
    }
  }
}
```

Marquei o trecho com a utilização de uma forma melhor com o comentário "Principal Alteração". Se possível veja o diff em um editor da sua preferência.
Uma outra dica é com relação a utilização do método ToUpper() para não esbarrar em erros com letras maiúsculas, minúsculas.
Espero ter ajudado.
Abraços,